# Rails routes - context for nested resource url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-routes

I'm trying to create a nested path for a show action of a nested resource

user.rb

```
has_many :fan_receives, as: :fanzone_owner, class_name: "FanActivity"
```

fan_activity.rb

```
belongs_to :fanzone_owner, polymorphic: true
```

In my routes.rb

```
match ":fanzone_owner_id/posts/:id", to: "fan_activities#show", via: :get
```

The path works, but the fanzone_owner_id could be anything. For an example,

example.com/1/fan_activities/2 *works* 
example.com/2/fan_activities/2 *also works* 
example.com/anythingatall/fan_activities/2 *also works*

I would like to make it so the fanzone_owner_id of the url must match the foreign key of the fan_activity, otherwise we redirect to 404.

Would I do this with validation check of the url in the controller? I'm not sure if this approach is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I just had to use the params from the url in the controller for the show action.

In the fan_activities_controller.rb

```
@user = User.find(params[:fanzone_owner_id])
@fan_activity = @user.fan_receives.find(params[:id])
```

If the user is not found or the user isn't the fanzone_owner, then it would be a 404.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the informations I would suggested to use [nested routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

```
resources :fanzone_owner do
 resources :fan_receive
end
```

For that you should've also [nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) ready, otherwise the above routing would make no sense at all. [This tutorial](https://www.amooma.de/screencasts/2015-01-22-nested_forms-rails-4.2/) could be helpful.

Comment: In my case, things get a little complicated because fanzone_owner is set as polymorphic and fan_receives are actually another class called 'fan_activities'

I tried using the nested routes, but it resulted in the same problem in the question. My goal is to just have the ':show' route for fan_receives display the context of who the fanzone_owner is.